# Ошибка конвертации .ui в .py - Pyside2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

При попытке конвертации **`.ui`** формы в **`.py`** файл, используя команду

```
pyside2-uic report_ui.ui > report_ui_frame.py
```

Получаю ошибку:

> An unexpected error occurred. 
> Check that you are using the latest version of PySide2 and report the error to
> http://bugs.openbossa.org, including the ui file used to trigger the error.

При этом файл **`.py`** создается, с формами и виджетами, но в блоке русского текста (в форме интерфейса должен быть использован русский язык), всего 2 строки:

```
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

При этом выполнение команды конвертации через *PyQt5* выводит исправный код с наполненным блоком `retranslateUi`.

Что тут поломано и как это исправить?

Comment: Вы из принципа используете `pyside2-uic`, или просто хотите подключить gui-форму к проекту?

Comment: @alexander-chernin Цель была использовать библиотеку под LGPL, сейчас я, пока что, допускаю использование PyQt5 под GPL в проекте. В любом случае, это странная ошибка, не дающая получить исходный код для UI